# Menu script that submits command to background, how do I kill it if needed?

Tags: raspbian, bash

I have a bash menu that displays my 4 sprinkler zones. The commands are submitted to a background process.

I would like to add another menu option that kills any current background processes spawned by the script and turn off any GPIO pins. How can I do this?

This is my current code:

```
sprinklermenu.sh
-----------------
#!/bin/bash

MYITEMS="One Two quit"

select myitem in $MYITEMS
do
    case $myitem in
    One)
    echo "Zone 1"
    bash TestTimerInBackground.sh 1&
    ;;
    Two)
    echo "Zone 2"
    ;;
    quit)
    echo "Quit was selected"
    break;
    ;;
    esac
done
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have several alternatives, for example:

1. Find the processes by name as [@tlhingan](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/users/46969/tlhingan) suggested
2. Save the PIDs of the started processes in a file
3. Save the PIDs of the started processes in memory

I'm not sure how you plan to use this script.
For example, should it be allowed to run `./TestTimerInBackground.sh 1` multiple times? (The same zone multiple times.).

Here's an example of collecting the PIDs in memory,
and allowing a zone only once.

```
#!/bin/bash

options=("Zone One" "Zone Two" "Quit")
pids=()
zones=()

select item in "${options[@]}"
do
    case $REPLY in
    [12])
        num=$REPLY
        echo "Zone $num was selected"
        if [ "${zones[$num]}" ]; then
            echo Zone already running
        else
            zones[$num]=1
            ./TestTimerInBackground.sh 1 &
            pids+=($!)
        fi
        ;;
    3)
        echo "Quit was selected"
        for pid in ${pids[@]}; do
            kill $pid
        done
        break
        ;;
    esac
done
```

Answer (score 3):

The general topic your are asking about (in case you need to Google more detailed info) is "job control."

Basically, shell commands `ps` and `kill` are what you will be playing with: `ps` lists processes, and `kill` kills them. You would have to parse ("have your script read and search") the output of `ps` in order to find the processes you are interested in, and then issue the `kill` command for them.